# how to make a long double 1-d array in c++ using new?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I'm trying to make it using:

```
long double *p = new long double[n];
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
scaffold.cpp:7:38: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
     long double *p = new long double[n];
```

Comment: What type is `n`? From your stated error, I believe it's not integral.

Comment: Why are you not using a vector?

Answer (score 3):

Your bug is that `n` is not an integral type.  That's the "expression in new-declarator" mentioned in the error message you got.  You don't show the code in your question, but if you have `int n = 100;` your code works fine, whereas if you have `float n = 100` you get the stated error.

Comment: What if i want to make an array dynamically of size greater than 32,767 ?